# addEventListener with 'mousedown' different than with 'click'

Tags: javascript, ajax, events, xmlhttprequest

I add addEventListener with a loop to a few anchor elements `productions` like this:

```
for(var j=0;j<productions.length;j++){
    productions[j].addEventListener('click',production_e,false);
}
```

Problem: This works but when I change it to 'mousedown' it follows the default anchor link after doing all the XHR fetching.

function production_e() tests for which "production" is clicked and then checks to see if it contains the description of the production. If not, it initiates a XHR to retrieve the description and inserts it into the production element.

```
function production_e(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(!current_show) {
    current_show = this;
    if(!this.getElementsByClassName('production_description')[0])
        get_production_article(this,show_description);
  }
}

get_production_article = function(production,callback) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
        if(req.readyState === 4 && req.status === 200) {
            install_article(production,req.responseText);
            callback(production);
        }
    }
    var pl = production.getElementsByClassName('production-link')[0];
    req.open('GET',pl.href + '-article',true);
    req.send();
}
```

The function `install_article` just inserts the responseText into the DOM and the callback function, which is `show_description` sets the styling to expose the element.

When I use `mousedown`, however, a left mouse click seems to perform all the same tasks but then follows the default anchor link to another page. Interestingly enough, a right mouse click works as I would expect the left mouse click to perform.

I'm guessing that somehow the preventDefault() function is not passing through or is re-triggered but I don't see how that is happening. What am I missing?

Comment: Well, preventing the mousedown defaults won't prevent the `click` event to occur and it's defaults with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, preventing the mousedown defaults won't prevent the `click` event to occur and it's defaults with it. You will have to listen to the click event as well to prevent the default `click` behavior.

Comment: But I specify 'mousedown' in addEventListener, not 'click' except in my original code.

Comment: @Rob You will need both, but in the `click` handler just do `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Why was I never informed of this?!!

Answer (score 0):

I usually try to avoid links for doing XHR's unless you want to leave the option for people who don't run javascript. Instead I would use a button and style it as a link if need be, and you can set a data-xxx attribute for any information you want to use for your XHR.

```
<button data-article="id0123" type="button" >Article 123</button>
```

then you can use: `e.currentTarget.dataset.article`

see if this codepen helps: http://codepen.io/pituki/pen/gtCus

Comment: The link is there for people who don't have javascript running so they get to another page with the same info. It's not disabled. A button, in my case, would be inappropriate. Nothing in your codepen applies to my problem.